# Unwanted Focus Shift when Clicking Menu Functions in Emacs Mode Line

Tags: focus, selected-window, easy-menu

I am experiencing an issue in Emacs where clicking on a function name in a menu displayed on the mode line not only triggers the desired function but also has an unintended effect on the window or buffer below, interfering with the intended functionality.

Creating a Minimal Working Example (MWE) for the menus, as they were generated using minor modes and easy-menu-define, would be challenging.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to diagnose and resolve this issue. If you've encountered a similar problem or have experience with focus shifts when using menus in the mode line, please share your insights. Thank you!

I thought that introducing a delay, let's say half a second, between the moment I click on the function name in the menu and its actual execution might solve the problem. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to implement this delay.

**Edit.** This is my MWE:

```el
(defun mwe-function-1 ()
  "MWE function 1"
  (interactive)
  (unwind-protect
      (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))
    ;; UNWINDFORMS
    (read-string "function 1 executed")))

(defun mwe-function-2 ()
  "MWE function 2"
  (interactive)
  (unwind-protect
      (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))
    ;; UNWINDFORMS
    (read-string "function 2 executed")))

(defun mwe-function-3 ()
  "MWE function 3"
  (interactive)
  (unwind-protect
      (query-replace "foo" "bar" nil (point-min) (point-max))
    ;; UNWINDFORMS
    (read-string "function 3 executed")))

(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter (:eval (propertize " MWE "
                              'face '(:foreground "RoyalBlue" :background "DarkGoldenrod1")))

  :keymap
  `(
    (,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . mwe-function)
    )

  (if mwe-mode
      (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
        "MWE"
        '("MWE mode"
          ;; I want the menu on mode-line only:
          :visible (not (eq (framep (selected-frame)) 'x))
          ["mwe-function-1" mwe-function-1
           :help "mwe-function 1"]
          ["mwe-function-2" mwe-function-2
           :help "mwe-function 2"]
          ["mwe-function-3" mwe-function-3
           :help "mwe-function 3"]))
    t))
```

```
emacs --version
GNU Emacs 29.1
Development version 28fb02492c24 on master branch; build date 2023-12-10.
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux ---- 5.4.0-169-generic #187-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 23 14:52:28 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
MATE
```

When I click on the function `mwe-function` in the menu, it doesn't get executed because the mouse event interrupts `query-replace`. The issue doesn't occur consistently and is quite random.

I would try to add a dalay between the mouse event on the menu and the function execution.

**Edit 2.** I updated my MWE adding an UNWINDFORM to my functions and my `Emacs` version. Now I am on `Emacs 29.1`.

It continues to happen, randomly, that `query-replace` gets interrupted by mouse capture within the buffer window.

Indeed (from the manual):

> Aside from this, any other character exits the `query-replace`, and is
> then reread as part of a key sequence. Thus, if you type `C-k`, it exits
> the `query-replace` and then kills to end of line. In particular, `C-g`
> simply exits the `query-replace`.

However, the UNWIND-FORM is always executed.

[image]

Comment: "Creating a Minimal Working Example (MWE) for the menus, as they were generated using minor modes and easy-menu-define, would be challenging." -- The amount of code to define a minimal minor mode and menu is very small -- just provide a working example that way.

Comment: Please include your Emacs version and platform in the question.

Comment: @phils I added the MWE but the issue is quite random.

Comment: @Drew I added the requested info

Comment: I updated my question adding a new MWE and a GIF. I also updated my `Emacs` to 29.1.

Comment: You could minimize this example a lot more by removing two of the three functions and corresponding menu items, removing the fontification in the modeline, etc. All of those appear to be extraneous details. That said, I cannot reproduce this. I click the menu item, I answer no until `query-replace` finishes, then hit enter when I see the final “function 1 executed” prompt. It is hard to tell what your gif is doing, but whatever it is must be caused by some other part of your Emacs config, or by the system you are running on, your hardware, etc.

Comment: @db48x Since the issue is random in the GIF I give `C-g` to abort the function when it works in the right way. In the MWE the issue is "rare" but in the my normal setting the issue happens more frequently.

Comment: Well, like I said, the issue _never_ happens here. Bisect your Emacs configuration, examine your window manager setup, try a different mouse, wait until a different phase of the moon, etc.

Comment: @db48x I write code for a team and the issue happens on other machines with different settings (Linux Distro, Emacs version... etc.).

Comment: You’ve still got to narrow it down to something concrete. No way to fix it otherwise. It’s not some universal bug in Emacs that everyone has just been putting up with for years. It’s something that is affecting only you and your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a bug ticket for this issue ([bug#69236](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=69236)) and a developer asked to me to

> show the output of "C-h l" in both cases, i.e. when things work and
> when they don't.

I got:

```
<help-echo> <down-mouse-1> ;; mouse-minor-mode-menu
q <return>                 ;; exit-minibuffer
<help-echo> C-h l          ;; view-lossage
```

when things work and:

```
<help-echo> <down-mouse-1>           ;; mouse-minor-mode-menu
<mouse-1> <mouse-1>                  ;; mouse-select-window
<help-echo> C-x o                    ;; other-window
<return>                             ;; exit-minibuffer
C-h l                                ;; view-lossage
```

when things do not work.

So I implemented a workaround to solve my problem (bug?):

1. First of all I builded this macro:

```el
(defmacro with-ignore-mouse-events (&rest body)
  "Macro to ignore mouse events before evaluating BODY."
  `(progn
     (when (input-pending-p)
       (let ((event (read-event)))
         (if (mouse-event-p event)
             (let ((button (event-basic-type event)))
               (if (eq button 'mouse-1)
                   (ignore)
                 (setq unread-command-events (list event))))
           (setq unread-command-events (list event)))))
     ,@body))
```

to intercept and "unread" the `mouse-1` event.

2. Then I prepared this function to create a modified version of the functions I intend to use in the menu:

```el
(defun generate-IME-star-functions (functions)
  "Generate starred versions of the given functions, where the original
functions are wrapped with the `with-ignore-mouse-events' macro"
  (dolist (func functions)
    (let* ((func-name (symbol-name func))
           (starred-func-name (intern (format "%s*" func-name))))
      (unless (fboundp starred-func-name)
        (defalias starred-func-name
          `(lambda ()
             (interactive)
             (with-ignore-mouse-events
              (funcall ',func)))
          (format "Starred version of the function `%s', where the original
function is wrapped with the `with-ignore-mouse-events' macro" func-name))))))
```

3. I built a list of the functions used in the menu:

```el
(defvar mwe-function-names '(mwe-function-1 mwe-function-2 mwe-function-3))
```

4. And, finally, I built the minor-mode menu in this way

```el
(define-minor-mode mwe-mode
  "MWE mode"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter (:eval (propertize " MWE "
                              'face '(:foreground "RoyalBlue" :background "DarkGoldenrod1")))

  :keymap
  `(
    (,(kbd "<C-kp-1>") . mwe-function)
    )

  (if mwe-mode
      (progn
        (generate-IME-star-functions mwe-function-names)
        (easy-menu-define mwe-menu mwe-mode-map
          "MWE"
          '("MWE mode"
            ;; I want the menu on mode-line only:
            :visible (not (eq (framep (selected-frame)) 'x))
            ["mwe-function-1" mwe-function-1*
             :help "mwe-function 1"]
            ["mwe-function-2" mwe-function-2*
             :help "mwe-function 2"]
            ["mwe-function-3" mwe-function-3*
             :help "mwe-function 3"])))
    t))
```

A better solution would have been to automatically wrap all functions, when launched from the menu, with my macro, but I have no idea how to accomplish that.